# Camera option not offered when "Choose File" button is selected from Responsive web-site program

Tags: java, android, android-studio, responsive-design

when I select the "Choose File" button on my app (WebView---Responsive web-site), I get the following options: "Drive", "Audio", "Downloads", "Sound Picker", "Gallery", "Photos", but the one I want is the Phone Camera. Can someone please help, I'm including a copy of my code for review. Thanks in advance for any help.

****activity_main.xml****

```
android:id="@+id/web1"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

****MainActivity.java****

```
package com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;




public class MainActivity extends Activity implements     AdvancedWebView.Listener  {

private AdvancedWebView web1;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web1 = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    WebSettings webSettings = web1.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web1.loadUrl("https://wastefreemail.com");
    web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        // ...
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        web1.onResume();
        // ...
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        web1.onPause();
        // ...
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        web1.onDestroy();
        // ...
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        web1.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!web1.onBackPressed()) { return; }
        // ...
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) { }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) { }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) { }






  }
```

****AndroidManifest.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />





<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


<activity android:name=".MainActivity">


</activity>
<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>



</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 12
    versionName "1.2.9"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-  optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

  dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-     core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'

 }
```

Comment: Is the choose file button inside the website?

Comment: yes the "Choose File" Button is inside of the web-site. If I open a browser page, go to our web-site from the phone and select the "Choose File" button it works fine, but not as part of the app.

Comment: So you need to ask the web developers of the website to provide the functionality to open the camera of the device from that button. Similar to they have the functionality for:  "Drive", "Audio", "Downloads", "Sound Picker", "Gallery", "Photos".

Comment: Umang, my developer said that the statement is <input type="file" id="image0" name="image0"  capture="camera" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"/>